# Using Newton's Law of Cooling how can we mathematically prove that our model accurately predicts when your substance reaches room temperature?

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function

So I have found this to be my formula for Newton's Law of Cooling:
   $ 76e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{59}{77}\right)t\right)} +23$

I need to figure out if my model acurately predicts when my substance reaches room temperature which is 23 degrees Celsius. Here is my working out, but I believe it is wrong because I am getting a really weird answer. I based it off a Khan Academy video.

T(t) = $ 76e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{59}{77}\right)t\right)} +23$

23 =    $ 76e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{59}{77}\right)t\right)} +23$

0 =    $ 76e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{59}{77}\right)t\right)} +23$

$0/76$ =    $ e^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{59}{77}\right)t\right)}$

ln (0) = $ {\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{59}{77}\right)t\right)}$

t= $0/{\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{59}{77}\right)\right)}$

t = -infitiy/ -0.13

I am sure this is not right as it is not an actual time for when my substance reaches 23 degrees or that what I think. Can someone show me how to actually solve this

Comment: The model can never reach room temperature in finite time. You can get as close as you want but not actually hit $23^\circ$C.

Comment: Ohhh ok. So to prove if my model is accurate would you recommend using a residual analysis.

Comment: I don't understand enough of the problem you are trying to solve to make a useful comment.

Comment: Line $4$’s equation is false: $e^x$ can never be zero (and i think line 3 has a typo). As the other comment says, you never reach room temperature in a finite amount of time, just arbitrarily close to it. So pick a tolerance and find how long it takes to reach room temperature within that tolerance if you want a practical answer still.

Comment: You are going to heat some substance. Record the room temperature before you start. Also record the name of the substance and its volume. Heat the substance to close to boiling point and take a temperature reading. Once heated, record the temperature of the substance every 5 minutes for 60 minutes. @copper.hat

Comment: @jamie2020: Well, in an ideal world, it will never reach room temperature.

Comment: @jamie2020 sure. Doesn't change the fact that $e^x>0$ and the conclusions that the *model* implies.